# Modular code structure in Lua

Tags: lua, modularity, love2d

I've been working with Love2d recently to build a Conway's Game of Life implementation.

I really like the framework, but I haven't been able to figure out how to modularize my code, which I feel is crucial to solid code structure.

What I'm wanting to do is be able to import a file that has different functions in it and be able to access that through my main lua file. I have been able to write scripts and run entire files, but not specific functions.

Is there a way to do this in Lua? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Do `require` or `dofile` work in Love2d?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the require function in LÖVE. It works similarly to how it works in Lua.

```
-- lib.lua

local lib = {} -- table to store the functions

function lib.inc(x)
  return x + 1
end

return lib
```

And here is how you require it in another file (for example, main.lua) and use it:

```
local lib = require('lib')

function love.load()
  print(lib.inc(1)) -- prints '2' in the terminal
end
```

Comment: Concise and very helpful, that's just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help! You can also ask in the LÖVE forums, some of the guys there don't use SO.

Answer (score -1):

Lua supports modules. Here is a tutorial on using them http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModulesTutorial

Comment: Modules aren't really needed for what Benjamin is asking. Besides, the module function has several known flaws - http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaModuleFunctionCritiqued and I think it has been deprecated in Lua 5.2